# Function to reindex a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to reindex a couple of pandas dataframes. I want to the last index to move up to the first, and I aim to build a general function.

I could find the last index by using len. But how do I then get the index series range(1, (len(a)-1)) printed out like 1,2,3,4, etc.?

What would be a smart solution to this problem?

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'geo':['Nation', 'geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3', 'geo4', 'geo5', 'geo6', 'county']})
print(a.geo)

# This is what I want to achieve in a general function 
print(a.geo.reindex(index=[7, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6]))

# The last index can be located using len. But what about the rest?
print(a.geo.reindex(index=[(len(a)-1), 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6]))  


b=pd.DataFrame({'geo':['Nation', 'geo1', 'geo2', 'geo3', 'geo4',  'county']})
print(b.geo)
print(b.geo.reindex(index=[5, 0, 1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframes and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(pd.DataFrame({'geo': np.roll(a['geo'], shift=1)}))
```

An alternative way is to do:

```
print(a.iloc[np.arange(-1, len(a)-1)])
```

Comment: Thanks. It works and I have learned something new - np.roll! I also tried this: np.linspace(1,len(a), len(a)-1, endpoint=False) to get the index series from 1 to end.

Comment: Yup. Yours is also correct. you can do sth like this: `print(a.iloc[np.append(np.array([7]), np.linspace(0, len(a), len(a)-1, endpoint=False, dtype=int))])`

Comment: But then you have to do `a = a.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the index, as your solution changes the actual indices.